# Is it possible for PayPal IPN POST to be sometimes missing the "payment_status" field?

Tags: python, paypal, flask, paypal-ipn

The subject. When tested manually, the payment_status field was always present in the request. But there are a few entries in the log which indicate that, after

```
payment_status = request.form.get('payment_status')
```

payment_status was None.

Is such an occurrance possible - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading the docs, I see that this field is not mandatory for all transaction types.